# BCrypt.checkpw returning false

Tags: java, jbcrypt

I have a user row in my user table that has a password (don't worry, it's a dummy password) that was encrypted using `BCrypt.hashpw`:

```java
System.out.println(BCrypt.hashpw("1234", BCrypt.gensalt()));
// $2a$10$IIAj7Ft6yGWk6I7bmYUzy.1UrtHVbX.N5z1CdfhG3GGpIib06oDv.
```

I then want to verify that password using `BCrypt.checkpw`:

```java
System.out.println(BCrypt.checkpw("1234", "$2a$10$IIAj7Ft6yGWk6I7bmYUzy.1UrtHVbX.N5z1CdfhG3GGpIib06oDv."));
// false
```

Why does it return false?

Comment: Can't confirm, except if I explicitly copy your output values. If I just execute the first block and put the result into the second one and run it, it prints `true` (as expected). I suspect you made a copy/paste mistake somewhere. Can you [edit] your question to provide an actual [mre] with real data? Using `$2a$10$IIAj7Ft6yGWk6I7bmYUzy.` as the salt for a password of `1234` produces `$2a$10$IIAj7Ft6yGWk6I7bmYUzy.52NB7huyI3wwszRP.OxsqfVXBsQs3tS` for me and not the one you show in your code.

Comment: @JoachimSauer This was an important hint. I had set up a User object that took a password as a parametre. And in the constructor I would encrypt that password before inserting it, or checking it against the already inserted password, in the database. But I had apparently already encrypted the password in my `create` method before passing it into the User constructor — essentially the password had been encrypted twice when inserted into the database (which was not the intention), and I was only checking for the intended one encryption when verifying it. Thank you for the hint! Case closed. :-)